# Load JQuery from DNN in 2sxc13

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Is there a way to load JQuery library from the DNN install in a razor template without loading external links or relative paths to the file?
Something like @include(jquery). Even better if it checks if it is already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in 2sxc ;)

```
var page = GetService<ToSic.Sxc.Services.IPageService>();
page.Activate("jQuery");
```

See also https://docs.2sxc.org/net-code/razor/services/page-service-activate.html

Comment: Thanks. @Jeremy Farrance already linked the page where this is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

If your skin/theme loads query you already have it.  Check the available snippets and/or check the included apps to see how the 2sic folks do it.

Comment: The theme does include it. But I need to change into a non-jquery theme and the 2sxc 13, which also does not include it. That's why I need to include it in the razor template.

Comment: I think Daniel may have pre-answered your question in this blog post: Goodbye jQuery...
https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/bye-jquery-go-fetch-2sxc-12-10 - My apologies if I didn't read close enough and missed something. If you figure it out, please post your own answer below, Cheers!!